Cannot execute LocalPool executor from within another executor: EnterError
While running the actix web application I'm starting a thread to subscribe to my MQTT gateway. This works well for my REST API endpoints as long as I test them with swagger. But I want to send request with my flutter app which works but after a couple of seconds I get
cannot execute LocalPool executor from within another executor: EnterError. After sending the request from my Flutter App I'm also subscribing to a MQTT topic.
The Rust error comes from
async fn init() {
    // Connect to redis
    redis_service::RedisCache::init().await;

    // Error appears here
    thread::spawn(|| {
        // Wait for new messages
        crate::service::subscriber_service::subscriber();
    });
}

The MQTT subscriber is an Async Client using paho_mqtt.
My request looks like this:
dio.interceptors.add(ApiProviderTokenInterceptor());

    final res = await dio.post(path, queryParameters: query);
    if (context.mounted) {
      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        final mqtt = Mqtt();
        mqtt.subscribe();
        _displayDialog(context);
      } else {
        await dialog(
            context,
            "Scan fehlgeschlagen",
            "Der Scan ist fehlgeschlagen. Für Hilfe wende Dich bitte an einen Administrator"
        );
      }
    }

This is the Rust error:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/std/src/panicking.rs:665:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/core/src/panicking.rs:74:14
   2: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/core/src/result.rs:1679:5
   3: core::result::Result<T,E>::expect
             at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/core/src/result.rs:1059:23
   4: futures_executor::local_pool::run_executor
             at /home/isumis/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/futures-executor-0.3.30/src/local_pool.rs:81:18
   5: futures_executor::local_pool::block_on
             at /home/isumis/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/futures-executor-0.3.30/src/local_pool.rs:317:5
   6: paho_mqtt::token::Token::wait_for
             at /home/isumis/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/paho-mqtt-0.12.5/src/token.rs:563:9
   7: paho_mqtt::client::Client::connect
             at /home/isumis/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/paho-mqtt-0.12.5/src/client.rs:89:9
   8: isumis::service::publish_service::publisher
             at ./src/service/publish_service.rs:25:21
   9: isumis::service::blacklight_service::blacklight_res::{{closure}}
             at ./src/service/blacklight_service.rs:34:9
  10: isumis::service::subscriber_service::handle_blacklight::{{closure}}
             at ./src/service/subscriber_service.rs:173:26
  11: isumis::service::subscriber_service::message_loop::{{closure}}
             at ./src/service/subscriber_service.rs:137:22
  12: isumis::service::subscriber_service::subscriber::{{closure}}
             at ./src/service/subscriber_service.rs:102:33
  13: futures_executor::local_pool::block_on::{{closure}}
             at /home/isumis/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/futures-executor-0.3.30/src/local_pool.rs:317:23
  14: futures_executor::local_pool::run_executor::{{closure}}
             at /home/isumis/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/futures-executor-0.3.30/src/local_pool.rs:90:37
  15: std::thread::local::LocalKey<T>::try_with
             at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/std/src/thread/local.rs:283:12
  16: std::thread::local::LocalKey<T>::with
             at /rustc/eeb90cda1969383f56a2637cbd3037bdf598841c/library/std/src/thread/local.rs:260:9
  17: futures_executor::local_pool::run_executor
             at /home/isumis/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/futures-executor-0.3.30/src/local_pool.rs:86:5
  18: futures_executor::local_pool::block_on
             at /home/isumis/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/futures-executor-0.3.30/src/local_pool.rs:317:5
  19: isumis::service::subscriber_service::subscriber
             at ./src/service/subscriber_service.rs:81:23
  20: isumis::server::init::{{closure}}::{{closure}}
             at ./src/server.rs:178:9

How can I fix this problem in Rust?

Please include a [mre]. The code you've pasted does not even include the function you're calling on the new thread, which is listed in the backtrace and is likely where the problem actually lies. Reduce the program to a small snippet that we can run ourselves.

Spawning a new OS thread for your message queue connection doesn't sound right to me, unless you create a new single-threaded runtime inside of this thread. You probably should use actix_web::rt::spawn or tokio::task::spawn (depending on the runtime you are using) to create a new task that runs concurrently with other tasks (i.e. the HTTP requests your server receives), instead of creating a new thread.

Yes, thanks. That worked
